# How do you move an object without resizing it in Acrobat Pro?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Many times when I try to move a callout box or text box using the Select Object tool (R) or the Hand tool (H), I accidentally resize it. In photoshop, there is a Move tool (V) that lets you move an object without resizing. Is there a similar function in Acrobat Pro?

I am using Acrobat Pro 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to...

- ...first select the object,
- ...then move it with the cursor (arrow) keys only (not using the mouse)

??  (You could use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> for bigger or smaller movement steps...)